# Finding the first duplicate in an int array, java

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is a common interview question i came across, however i failed to improve it in the way it demands.

```
assume we have an int array int[] A, we want to find the first duplicate entry.
```

1. almost everyone can think of using a HashSet, and add to it while parsing.this will lead to O(n) time and O(n) space. After this I was asked to solve it without other data structures. I said the dumbest idea will be comparing each one in O(n^2) time. And then I was asked to improve the O(n^2) time.
2. And to improve it, i thought of using a fixed size array(assuming the maximum number is n), boolean[] b = new boolean[n]; however I was not allowed to use this method.
3. Then I thought of using an int variable, using bit manipulation, if the maximum number is smaller than 32, then for n we can push 1 to n bits left and | to a checker, then & the checker to the next entry in the array to check if it's > 0.
   e.g.:

   ```
   int c = A[i];
   if(check & (1 << c) > 0) return false;
   check |= 1 << c;
   ```

however this is not allowed either.

So there was an hint that I can use the array itself as hashset/hashtable, and "linear hashing"?

any help ? thanks

Comment: First 3 words on the description for the "interview-questions" tag...DO NOT USE.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to improve on the O(n) time?

Comment: Sort the array in-place using quicksort?

Comment: Sorting the array will make it impossible to identify the **first** duplicate entry.

Comment: What is the benefit of using hashset here rather than an ArrayList?

Comment: An ArrayList is backed by an array. He already has an array. How would adding a second array help? HashSet lookups are O(1). ArrayList lookups are O(n).

Comment: ArrayList lookups are not O(n), they're O(1). It doesn't matter how long your array is, finding the element at index 0 takes as long as any other element. Additionally, I'm not really sure if you *can* do this in better than O(n) time. Surely you'd need to examine every element of the array in order to find duplicates?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i have corrected the question a bit, "After this I was asked to solve it without other data structures. I said the dumbest idea will be comparing each one in O(n^2) time. And then I was asked to improve the O(n^2) time."

Comment: @Peter: By lookup, I mean arrayList.contains(i) (or hashSet.contains(i)). O(n) vs. O(1).

Comment: If you can have a constraint on the values of the array (0 < values < N < 2^31) then you can reach O(1) space and O(N/2) average time.

Comment: in the array `{1,2,2,1}` is 1 the first duplicate entree or 2?

Comment: @amit 2 should be the first duplicate

Comment: If 2 is first duplicate, I don't understand "first". 1 is the first number in the array that has a duplicate, by what criterion is 2 first?

Comment: @Mathias imo, while u looping from first to last int, 2 is the first one that can appeared 2 times. I think that makes it first?

Comment: I would have expected 1 to be the first, because 1 is the first element in the array that has a duplicate. Your definition, if I understand correctly, is "2 is first because its duplicate is the first encountered in the array".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear hashing as [defined by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing) has the advantage that resizing occurs incrementally, because buckets are split one-by-one in round-robin fashion, retaining constant amortized time complexity for insertion with resize. Their idea therefore is to iterate over the array, reusing the elements already iterated over as storage for linear hashing.

While I am far from an expert on linear hashing, I don't see any way to fit the hash table in the array. Granted, to store n elements with linear hashing, you might get by with using n buckets. However, the number of elements in a bucket being unbounded, you'd need something like a linked list to implement each bucket, which costs an additional O(n) memory for pointers.

As such, this algorithm does not yield a better asymptotic space complexity than an ordinary `HashSet`. It does reduce memory consumption by a constant factor, though.

Its time complexity is on par with the ordinary `HashSet`.

Edit: It appears to me this answer is being ignored (no votes, no comments). Is it not useful? Please comment so I know what to improve.

Comment: +1 from me, I read it carefully. I read other resources as well, a linear hash is a pretty heavyweight structure not at all suited to such minimalistic circumstances as we have here. It's got supporting structures and everything. I think that what the interviewers really meant was in a loose sense, a hashlike structure that gradually grows.

Answer (score 4):

I have this one idea: as you progress down the array, you sort the part that you have visited.  By employing binary search you'll improve time; space is 0. The sort itself is... insertion sort? You're basically running the sort as normal, but as you search for the place to insert the new numeber, if you hit the number itself, you shout "bingo". That's an improvement over zero space + O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I don't think it's what the interviewers are looking for. Like you are using the part of the array already examined as a sorted partition, I think they want that to be used as a dynamic hash table.

Comment: also it sounds like this can't go below n log(n) overal complexity, while any hashing solution should be able to do it in o(n)

Comment: Insertion sort being O(n^2), how is this an improvement?

Comment: @kritzikratzi I sincerely doubt you can implement a hashing algo with this kind of memory constraint and make it O(1). Keep also in mind that we're not talking just lookup, but lookup+insertion, with 1-sized buckets, so expanding with every insertion.

Comment: @marko it's not like i know this stuff, but it seems that's what linear hashing is made for. a way to shrink and grow a hashtable by one element at a time while maintaining approximately constant runtime (not taking any memory allocation into account).

Answer (score 4):

I would ask the interviewer(s) why they don't want you using "other data structures" when there is clearly a built-in structure designed for this purpose - `HashSet`.

1. It is O(n). You probably won't do much better than this using other methods, unless you do something really clever and get it down to O(log n).
2. This is Java - not C. There are readily available data structures to do this, painlessly, with almost no additional effort on the programmer's part.

From the [Java Documentation on the Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html):

> The collections framework is a unified architecture for representing
>   and manipulating collections, allowing them to be manipulated
>   independently of the details of their representation. It reduces
>   programming effort while increasing performance. It allows for
>   interoperability among unrelated APIs, reduces effort in designing and
>   learning new APIs, and fosters software reuse.

**Addendum**

Most of the comments below argue that this is merely an exercise - to determine the skills of the programmer. My counterargument to this is simple:

This "interview" is for a Java programming position. Java, being an object-oriented language, has the ability to perform tasks such as these without needing to design a process from scratch (like in C and various other low level languages). In addition, Java is not the best choice when space complexity is a concern. That said, read entry one in my list above again.

Comment: I think it is reasonable in interview questions to constrain what can be used in order to determine the interviewee's understanding of data structures. I think in this case they were looking for him to improve the space complexity, not the time complexity, i.e. do it in place.

Comment: @hatchet: I completely agree, but Java is OO and has the ability to perform tasks such as these without needing to design a process from scratch (like in C). In addition, Java isn't the best (code) base if concerns for space complexity are an issue.

Comment: @EvanMulawski This is not about Java, but about programming skills of the interviewee.

Comment: I think it would have been clearer if the interviewer just said, "Can you tell me a solution with O(n) time complexity, and O(1) space complexity." That would have unambiguously ruled out using external API data structures.

Comment: @evanMulawski then this might be an exercise to learn how to do this without a specific library, to know how such things actually work.

Comment: I understand the purpose of the exercise (as I have been asked these kinds of questions myself). But if the position you are interviewing for is centered around Java, you will never need to do anything like this.

Comment: @Evan You'll never have to implement anything space efficient in Java? ;) Well probably not worth the effort in 99% of all cases but rephrasing the question as "Propose a solution that runs better than O(N^2) time and needs O(1) additional memory" would be quite fine

Answer (score 2):

well, you give the answer yourself: linear hashing does exist. it has complexity o(1)/o(1) according to http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~ad/MDE515/e_ds_linearhashing.pdf
so you'd take out elements from the array one after the other while using the first few as memory for the hash map.
but really, it's a datastructure that you implement yourself.

either the interview didn't say you'd have to solve it "without other data structures" or the interviewer did in fact not understand that a datastructure is a datastructure even if you implement it yourself.

rofls anyways, mostly because it's the kind of question that you either know, or you don't. there's no way to come up with this during an interview. i hope you won't work for them.

Comment: +1 for just the answer i was looking for, i agree with you that it's the kind of question that "you either know or you don't " lol.

Comment: But do you have a concrete idea how to implement this with the memory constraints at hand? After a brief study of that paper, it isn't at all obvious to me.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik well i think this should be the right direction cuz the interviewer asked me if i had heard of linear hashing, however im still trying to work it out lol

Comment: I'd just find it disappointing if this question amounted to nothing but a google query, and one with incomprehensible results. Sounds like an attractive problem.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik ok i will not choose the best answer for now, until me or someone else give the acceptable solution with linear hashing. thanks for your solution tho it's nice.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik well, yes, there's no code in my answer. to me that's besides the point because 1.) the code won't be a happy two-liner, it will be disgusting and unreadable and maybe 30-50 lines long 2.) code is online. just google linear hashing sample. 3.) the question  wasn't "how does one implement linear hashing" 4.) as i mentioned, the question as posed by the interviewer is imho a bit silly, because even if you hide the datastructure in the beginning of the array, it's still an extra datastructure. any other solution MUST obviously have > O(n) complexity. oh well, whatever ... :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik also: i'm certainly too lazy to dig into linear hashing and try to adopt it to fit exactly with this example. if you're willing to do so... i'm most curious to see the result

Comment: @RuoboWang My idea is unfortunately still not good enough as insertion  sort is O(n^2) on average. The good thing about it is the basic principle of mutating the traversed part of the array to optimize lookup. I'd really like it if something neat was built on top of that.

Comment: @kritzikratzi I have now tried quite hard to find out the insertion complexity of the linear hash, but they only mention lookup cost.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: See my answer for insertion cost.

Answer (score 2):

This does not use linear hashing, but works faster than O(N<sup>2</sup>):

1. Choose some small number C and use a brute-force algorithm to find first duplicate for the first C elements of the array. Clear first C elements if nothing found yet.
2. Perform the remaining steps with first N elements empty. Initially, N=C. After each iteration, N is doubled.
3. Sequentially add numbers from indexes N+1 .. 3*N/2 to the hash table in first N array elements. Use open addressing. After all N/2 elements moved, hash load factor should be 1/2. Clear space, occupied by N/2 elements we just moved. For the next N/4 elements, search each of them in the hash table(s), constructed so far, then hash them to the space which is always twice as much as number of elements. Continue this until N-C array elements are hashed. Search the remaining C elements in the hash tables and compare them to each other.
4. Now we have N array elements without duplicates, occupying 2*N space. Rehash them in-place.
5. Sequentially search all other elements of the array in this hash table. Then clear these 2*N elements, set N=2*N, and continue with step 3.

Steps 3..5 may be simplified. Just hash elements N+1 .. 3*N/2 and search all other elements of the array in this hash table. Then do the same for elements 3*N/2+1 .. 2*N. This is twice as slow as the original algorithm, but still O(N log N) on average.

Other alternative is to use first N empty elements to construct a binary search tree for elements N+1 .. 3*N/2 and search all other elements of the array in this tree. Then do the same for elements 3*N/2+1 .. 2*N. (This works only if array is small enough and its elements may be indexed by integer values).

---

Algorithm, described above, is probabilistic and works in O(N log N) time on average. Its worst case complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>). The alternative with a binary search tree may have O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) worst case complexity if tree is self-balancing. But this is complicated. It is possible to do the task in O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) worst case time with simpler algorithm.

This algorithm sequentially iterates through the array and keeps the following invariant: largest possible sub-array with size that is a power-of-two, that fits to the left of current position, starts at index 0 and is sorted; next such sub-array follows it and is also sorted; etc. In other words, binary representation of current index describes how many sorted sub-arrays are preceding it. For example, for index 87 (1010111) we have a single element at index 86, a sorted pair at index 84, a sorted sub-array of 4 elements at 80, a sorted sub-array of 16 elements at 64, and a sorted sub-array of 64 elements at the beginning of the array.

1. Iterate through the array
2. Search current element in all preceding sub-arrays using binary search.
3. Sort current element together with those preceding sub-arrays, that correspond to trailing "ones" in the binary representation of current index. For example, for index 87 (1010111), we need to sort current element together with 3 sub-arrays (1+1+2+4=8 elements). This step allows adding current element to sub-arrays while keeping algorithm's invariant.
4. Continue with next iteration of step 1.

Comment: Nice idea to do log(n) passes over the array to keep a good load factor in the hashtables. However, your complexity analysis seems to assume lookups in the hash tables to take constant time. Is this really true if we use open adressing?

Comment: The more I learn about it, the more obvious it is to me that linear hashing is a red herring here. Its only benefit is in situations like transactional dbms's since the time cost of every insert is balanced, instead of having sharp drops when the whole hash is being expanded at once. A nice idea of yours that I missed was to start with brute force until enough space is recovered for a meaningful data structure. It's asymptotic performance that counts.

Comment: One question, though: once you clear out the first C elems, how will you know when you encounter an entry that is the duplicate of one of those first C elems?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Step 1 compares each of these C elements with every other element in the array.

Comment: @meriton Oh, I see. Not only between themselves, but through the whole array. That's an initial hit of O(CN) then.

Comment: which, since C is constant, is O(n).

Comment: @meriton: D.Knuth, The art of computer programming, Vol 3, Chapter 6.4 gives lots of formulas for various open addressing algorithms. For example, linear probing (the simplest of them) needs about `0.5 * (1 + 1 / (1 - a)^2)` probes in case of unsuccessful search. If load factor is 0.5, this gives 2.5 probes (even less in case of successful search). So lookups take O(2.5)=O(1) time.

Comment: This is very nice work, Evgeny. It deserves being accepted at least three times over :)

Answer (score 0):

I was presented this with the additional restriction of no additional memory, only the registers. This was what I came up with:

```
outer: for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
 for (j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
   if (arr[i] == arr[j])
     break outer;
```

If i and j are < arr.length, the are the indices of the first duplicate value and it's match.

It's just a little better than O(n^2) since j never cover the entire length of arr

Comment: Worst/average case is still O(n^2), but this is a good solution for no additional space.

Comment: ya I thought of this too, however this is not the one those ppl wants D:

Comment: You can decrease your constant factor by changing the comparison in the outer loop to i < arr.length - 1, since there is nothing to do when i == arr.length - 1. In addition, your break will only bail out of the inner loop, and will continue iterating in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
res = -1;
startArray = [...];
sortedArray = mergeSort(startArray);
for i = 1 to n
     x = bynary_search(sortedArray, startArray[i]); //array, element
     if ((sorted_array[x] == sortedArray[x-1])    ||   (sorted_array[x] == sortedArray[x+1]))
           res = i;
           break;
if (res != -1)
     print('First duplicate is ',startArray[res]);
else
     print('There are no duplicates');
```

Merge sort worst case                    **O(n log n)**

Binary search worst case                 **O(log n)**

n times Binary search worst case         **O(n log n)**

*Total                                    **O(n log n)***

Comment: p.s. Special cases are when X is first (last) element then there is no  sortedArray[x-1] (or in case x is last element, sorted array[x+1])
so there is also that small adjustment

Answer (score 0):

Here is O(n) Time on an Average algorithm

```
public static int firstRepeatingElement(int[] elements) {
    int index = -1;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i = elements.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (set.contains(elements[i])) {
            index = i;
        }
        set.add(elements[i]);
    }
    if (index != -1) {
        return elements[index];
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No repeating elements found");
}
```

Here is the test cases

```
@Test
public void firstRepeatingElementTest() {
    int [] elements = {1,2,5,7,5,3,10,2};
    int element = ArrayUtils.firstRepeatingElement(elements);
    assertThat(element, is(2));
}

@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void firstRepeatingElementTestWithException() {
    int [] elements = {1,2,5,7,3,10};
    int element = ArrayUtils.firstRepeatingElement(elements);
    assertThat(element, is(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the "linear hashing" solution that your interviewers were looking for.  We first need to assume two additional constraints:

1. length of A is >=  max value of A
2. All values of A are positive

With these additional constraints we can solve the problem using less time and space.

Ok, let's get to the code:

```
int findFirstDuplicateEntry(int[] A) {
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if (A[Math.abs(A[i])-1]<0)
            return Math.abs(A[i]);
        else {
            A[Math.abs(A[i])-1] = -A[Math.abs(A[i])-1];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

What I am doing here is using the array itself to store some additional information.  As I iterate through the array, each time I come across a value, I will use that value as an **index**.  At this index I will check the value. If the value is negative, I know that I have been here before (because of the all positive constraint). Therefore I have found my first duplicate, and can exit. Otherwise, I will negate the value at that index.